# How to send a message to errorChannel when an exception occurs in spring integration?

Tags: exception, spring-integration

Hi I have an spring integration flow where my message traverse through multiple Deserialization, transformation and serialization process.

I am unable to handle any exception that are thrown during the process. I have defined my error channel as below. How to interrupt the integration flow and send the message to error channel?
================ error channel ===============

```
    @Bean("errorChannel")
    public MessageChannel errorChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    @Router(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter handleError(){
        ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter router = new ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter();
        Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
        mappings.put(RuntimeException.class.getName(), "someChannel");
        mappings.put(Exception.class.getName(), "someChannel");
        router.setChannelMappings(mappings);
        return router;
    }
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "someChannel")
    public void handleErrors(Message<?> message)  {
        LOGGER.info(" error caught in some channel {}", message);
    }
```

============== error emitting channel ====================

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "JSON_to_IM_in_Process")
    public AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler  json_to_im_svc() throws Exception {

    AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler  mh =  new AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler () {
            
    @Override
    public Message<?>  handleRequestMessage(Message<?> inputMessage) {
            
        String inputRecord = inputMessage.getPayload().toString();
        Map<String, Object> newheader = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        InputModel result = null; 
******if(true) throw new RuntimeException("forcefully Exception ");******
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            result = mapper.readValue(inputRecord, InputModel.class);
            newheader.put("Exception_Status", "Passed");
            Message<?> outMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(result).copyHeaders(inputMessage.getHeaders())
                    .copyHeaders(newheader).build();

            LOGGER.info("Deserialized to Input Model -------------->" + outMsg);
            return outMsg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            newheader.put("Exception_Status", "Failed");
            String excep = "Exception in translating inputFormat to Object";
            Message<?> outMsg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(excep).copyHeaders(inputMessage.getHeaders())
                    .copyHeaders(newheader).build();
            LOGGER.info("Exception in translating inputFormat to Object", e.getMessage());
            return outMsg;
        }
    }
```

I want to catch the exception in the errorChannel but unable to do so. I want to break the integration flow from the exception I want to execute "someChannel" and stop and send to the outboundRequest channel.
If the exception is inside the try{} block it is handled by the catch block. If the exception is outside the try block the stack trace is coming directly on the console.

**What I need to do more to catch the exceptiopn in the errorChannel ?**

Comment: You need to show the main integration components in the flow (that throws the exception).

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with the error emitting section.

Comment: That is not enough; we need to see the complete integration flow, from start to end.

Comment: You just don't throw any exception from your `inputDeserialize()`. You swallow it, build a new message and return. The transformer treats a return as a reply message and sends it into its output channel. Not sure why you talk about error message here if your code doesn't go that direction. See docs about error handling: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling

Comment: Thanks Bilan for the reply. I went through the docs and prepared the error channel.... But I am still unable to catch the exception in errorchannel. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Right. And where do you throw an exception so frameworks would know to wrap into an `ErrorMesaage` and send to that `errorChannel`?

Comment: I am throwing an exception there ******if(true) throw new RuntimeException("forcefully Exception ");******